# How to dynamically determine RootState type in redux toolkit with makeStore function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get the type of my redux store in order to declare the `RootState` type. Up until now I was creating and exporting a `store` instance as specified in the redux toolkit docs and faced no problems whatsoever, but now for various reasons I want to have a `makeStore` function to return a new store every time I call it.

My problem is that while I have a working implementation, the type of `RootState` is `any` which results in no autocomplete recommendations.

My code is the following:

```
import {
    configureStore,
    combineReducers,
    EnhancedStore,
    ConfigureStoreOptions,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import { cartReducer } from '@hooks';

import appReducer from './reducer';
import rootSaga from './saga';

export const makeStore: (
    initialState?: ConfigureStoreOptions['preloadedState']
) => EnhancedStore = (initialState = {}) => {
    const persistConfig = {
        key: 'root',
        version: 1,
        storage,
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
        persistConfig,
        combineReducers({ app: appReducer, cart: cartReducer })
    );

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: persistedReducer,
        preloadedState: initialState,
        middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
            getDefaultMiddleware({
                thunk: false,
                serializableCheck: {
                    ignoredActions: [
                        FLUSH,
                        REHYDRATE,
                        PAUSE,
                        PERSIST,
                        PURGE,
                        REGISTER,
                    ],
                },
            }).concat(sagaMiddleware),
    });

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
};

const store = makeStore();
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>; // this is "any"
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch; // this is "Dispatch<AnyAction>"

export default store;
```

I think the most probable cause of the problem lies in `EnhancedStore` which is a generic and looks like that:

```
export interface EnhancedStore<S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction, M extends Middlewares<S> = Middlewares<S>> extends Store<S, A> {
    /**
     * The `dispatch` method of your store, enhanced by all its middlewares.
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    dispatch: DispatchForMiddlewares<M> & Dispatch<A>;
}
```

I am not really sure what `S` is supposed to be, so I don't pass anything to it and it defaults to `any`.

My question is, what is the best way to get the store state type when using redux-toolkit and a `makeStore` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your return type.

The real return type is much more nuanced and you are throwing that information out of the window by assigning one yourself.

```
export const makeStore: (
    initialState?: ConfigureStoreOptions['preloadedState']
) = (initialState = {}) => {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Removing the return type does indeed infer the correct type for the RootState variable. I would like to know however if there is a way to fully type the makeStore function.

Comment: As the author of most types of Redux Toolkit: the return types of those functions are generics that contain the full item you put into them. Manually typing them will essentially mean copy-pasting your whole code. 
They are not meant to be manually typed, they are explicitly created to be used purely with inference.